# Unsolvability of word problems in Groups

Tags: combinatorial-group-theory

I was reading Rotman's "An Introduction to the theory of Groups" Chapter 12 "The Word Problem". I cannot understand the key concepts of Turing Machines and undecidibilty. I want to prove understand the proof "There exists a finitely presented group which has unsolvable word problem". Can anyone point out any beginner friendly reference to reading this theorem?
And maybe chalk out a outline how this proof goes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I'd recommend starting with the word problem before learning about Turing Machines and Undecidability.  That said, the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) on the Word problem outlines the situation and includes several references.  It even gives an explicit presentation for a group with undecidable word problem.

Comment: You are asking somebody here to write a chapter in a textbook on the theory of algorithms. Mathstackexchange is not meant for this. What's wrong with reading an existing textbook?